# Get "Foreign key references invalid table" error when the table exists

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, sql-server-2012

I have three tables

```
Create table PROPERTY(
    property_number     int,
    property_name       int,
    property_type       varchar(30),
    property_street     varchar(30),
    property_city       varchar(30),
    property_zip        int,
    constraint PK_PROPRETY_NUMBER primary key(property_number)
)

Create table SERVICE(
    service_ID              int,
    service_description     varchar(150),
    service_amount          money,
    constraint PK_SERVICE_ID primary key(service_ID),
)

Create table SERVICEHISTORY(
    service_ID          int,
    service_date        date,
    property_number     int,
    constraint PK_SERVICEHISTORY_ID primary key(service_ID, service_date),
    constraint FK_SERVICE_ID foreign key(service_ID)
            references SERVICE(service_ID),
    constraint FK_PROPERTY_NUMBER foreign key(property_number)
            references PROPERTY(property_number)
)
```

I run the first two successfully, and they appear in the Object Explorer under "Tables".  In SERVICEHISTORY, the "references SERVICE", and, "PROPERTY" are erred.  When I run that script, I get:

```
Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 11
Foreign key 'FK_SERVICE_ID' references invalid table 'SERVICE'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 11
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific DBMS you're using.

Comment: In MySQL, it works fine.  Maybe your DBMS doesn't allow using service_ID as primary key and foreign key :-/

Comment: It's SQL Server 2012.  It's happening for the property_number as well as the service_ID.

Comment: I'm surprised your first two queries ran successfully because you didn't declare your pk fields as not null.

Comment: In SQL Server 2008 (via [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0afd5)) runs without errors.

Comment: The same for SQL Server 2012: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0afd5

Comment: Do you run it as a single script?

Comment: Welp, I guess I was not using the correct database. It runs successfully after I "Use *Correct Database*".  Sorry about that. Thanks for your help!